# Try to use "GameHelperUtils" package in my Project :Error when building with gradlew.bat : Package does not exist

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, dependency-management, build-error, gradlew

I'm soo damn desperate,and totaly stuck since 2 DAYS with simply adding 2 Projects to my project and compile a android Debuging version with the console.

I set up the Project with LibGDX gradle and everything worked fine until i addet 2 Projects to the Workspace and used them as librarys : 
-BaseGameUtils 
-google-play-service

Setting them up in eclipse worked also fine, but compiling a androidDebug.apk with the console gives this error:
error: package com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper does not exist
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
                                            ´`

My build.gradle looks like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/raw/maven-repo/' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.4'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10+'
    classpath 'com.github.jtakakura:gradle-robovm-plugin:0.0.8'
}
```

}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

```
version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = 'FlappysSpaceAdventure'
    gdxVersion = '1.0.1'
    roboVMVersion = '0.0.12'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
}
```

}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
}
```

}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

```
configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"



    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')

}
```

}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

```
configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
    compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":core")

    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
}
```

}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

```
dependencies {

    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    compile "aurelienribon:tweenengine:6.3.3"
    compile "aurelienribon:tweenengine:6.3.3:sources"
}
```

}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}

and the classpath file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="src" path="/FlappysSpaceAdventure-core"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.classpathcontainer"/>
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/BaseGameUtils"/>
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/google-play-services_lib"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
```

I really don't know what to do, i feel so stupid...i cant understand why this is happening.

Comment: I had this same issue. Android's version of Gradle is not compatible with Eclipse. They have added extra syntax that Eclipse's Gradle plugin does not understand. You cannot use the Gradle command line to compile an APK using Eclipse library projects. If you are using Eclipse, Gradle is only good for generating the initial libgdx project, but you need to compile APK's the traditional way with ADT. If you want APK build automation, you need to switch to Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you Very much for your Reply. So you Recommend to set everything up again in Android Studio? When i use the ADT compiler i get Multiplex errors, on packages, wich I imported with gradle...

Comment: I would. Although I haven't used libraries with it yet I haven't heard of that being an issue. I've set it up to do build flavors and it's a huge time saver when you have free and paid versions of an app, or an Amazon store version.

Comment: Very Usefull information Thank you very very much! Last question is:
Do you know if it is possible, to also compile a IOS version, when i switched over to Android studio?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you need to be on a Mac. I haven't done that yet.

Comment: Thank you a Lot! I set up Android studio, corrected the dependencies and now gradlew is compiling again, without errors, and eclipse compiled whitout errors anyways, even before, but Android studio gives me errors and is not able to start the app...so i go on working with eclipse, and everytime i need to include a project i use android studios..i mean, even when you change the theme into "dracula" and then back to "default" half of the workspace stays dark..:) they need to improve it a litte